# Excluding CRUD resources when only setting up member routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, model-view-controller, routes, resources

I've nested routes for my `Dish` actions inside of those of `Restaurants`. The only problem is I only need the member based routes and not the standard CRUD based actions. Is there a way I can exclude them all without having to fully write out every resource as so:

```
resources :dishes, except: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :show, :destroy] do
  ...
end
```

or

```
resources :dishes, only: [:like, :unlike, :dislike, :undislike] do
  ...
end
```

**Current Setup**

```
  resources :restaurants do
    resources :dishes do
      member do
        put "like",      to: "dishes#like"
        put "unlike",    to: "dishes#unlike"
        put "dislike",   to: "dishes#dislike"
        put "undislike", to: "dishes#undislike"
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: if you do this `resources :dishes, only: [] do` . this will not generate CRUD routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:only` option tells Rails to create only the specified routes. Now if you pass empty array to the only option, it will not create any because it is expecting the action names in the array.

So this will work

```
resources :dishes, only: [] do
```

Reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/routing.html ( 4.6 Restricting the Routes Created)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like
`resources :restaurants do
    resources :dishes, only: [] do
      member do
        put "like",      to: "dishes#like"
        put "unlike",    to: "dishes#unlike"
        put "dislike",   to: "dishes#dislike"
        put "undislike", to: "dishes#undislike"
      end
    end
  end`